# Is it pejorative to use "old girl" to refer to a woman?

Tags: idioms, british-english, pejorative-language

Does it encompass any specific age group? (young, middle-aged, elderly, all of them)

I heard it in an old film and read it once in sentences like:

> - "Come on, old girl, cheer up."
> - "Who is that old girl you were talking to?"

[old girl](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/old+girl) - a familiar name used to refer to a woman

EDIT - So as to avoid multiple interpretations of the idiom, and too many answers, let's keep this question to its use in BrE.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There are essentially two distinct and different uses.

Former pupils of schools are sometimes known as 'Old Boys' and 'Old Girls'. *David Cameron, the present Prime Minister is an **Old Boy** of Eton College*. *Princess Anne is an **Old Girl** of Benenden School in Kent*. The use may be becoming dated, with more and more schools converting to co-ed, and the increasing use of 'former pupil'. (How boring!)

Both *Old Boy* and *Old Girl*, are hearty backslapping terms of endearment among social equals, more often in the upper strata of society. It is a bit like the working-class expression 'mate', but in a higher social register. *Old Boy*, especially, has a military officer ring about it. Again one senses that calling people ***old girl*** or ***old boy*** has been in decline for several decades.

Though it is non-pejorative I would counsel any visitor to Britain to take care how they use it. It is a term which could sound slightly preposterous if used in an inappropriate register.

Comment: Good answer: I'd emphasise the 'social equals' element, and add that it would only really be used referring to someone you know very well. This is one of those phrases which should be avoided unless you're totally confident you're using it properly

Comment: Neat, I learned something - namely, the etymology of the phrases "old boy's [network/club]", being the only place you really see "old boy" in American English.

Comment: @JonStory There is a further use which I didn't mention, but not one you use directly to a person's face - a bit like referring to them by their surname only. Let's say I have unsatisfactory dealings with a family firm, after speaking to one of the sons or daughters. My friend says 'You need to speak to 'the old boy' - he'll understand the problem'. So 'old boy' and 'old girl' can be used **at a distance** to refer to just about anyone, and often are. I do not consider it disrespectful as it can as frequently be a compliment as a derogation, implying greater seniority and experience.

Comment: I've never heard it used like that other than someone talking about a close friend/family member - eg 'my wife will know, but you'll have to talk to the old girl yourself' - in the context you give, the son is saying 'the old boy' (more often 'the old man') referring to their own parent, a close relationship. You'd never refer to your boss like that if it wasn't your father....

Comment: @JonStory I have worked for companies where people would refer to the boss, and not disrespectfully, as 'the old man'. But that wasn't the situation I had in mind. Let's say I am a customer of Edwards and Sons Ltd. I can't get any joy out of the two sons who are singularly unhelpful. My friend says 'you need to speak to the "old boy", he's much more experienced'. On a different note, some people do use this to refer to their parents. I never did, though when he was alive I would sometimes talk about 'my old chap'.

Comment: I'm surprised by the companies you've worked for, as that seems excessively familiar even compared to small hyper-friendly family run businesses I've worked for. Although I understand your analogy now - ie when the subject of the sentence (the old boy himself) can't hear it to be offended. I'd still suggest it's being used relative to the sons, though.

Comment: @JonStory I'm probably going back a decade or two. It would probably sound a bit strange nowadays, as people are so conscious of committing errors of political correctness. I'm old enough to have had a life before all that!

Answer (score 7):

According to [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/old-girl), the expression 'old girl' is used in different situations, and   the age group of reference may be different according to context. It is not generally considered pejorative:

> - (British)  a former female student of a school or college:
>     one of the college’s most famous old girls
> - A former female member of a sports team or company:
>     other old girls of this magazine have done well
> - informal , (chiefly British) an elderly woman:
>     they’re a couple of harmless old girls
> - an affectionate form of address to a girl or woman:
>     he said, ‘Don’t worry, old girl’

Answer (score 3):

*Is it pejorative to use “old girl” to refer to a woman?*

I think it **cannot** be used pejoratively: because if you call someone an "old boy" or "old girl", you simultaneously mean to to say that you yourself are, that everyone is, also an old boy or old girl.

---

It's "familiar", i.e. you can use it to someone if they are family.

The term "old boy" is normally used, or perhaps I should say it's also used, for someone who used to be at a "school": see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_Boys

So you can use it to a stranger if (only if) you want to say, "Although you're not my family, we both  went to the same type of school, and so we have that experience and those social values in common."

So you could use it in a phrase like, "Cheer up, old boy!" or "Steady on, old girl!". But it is being "familiar". And perhaps self-consciously archaic, these days.

---

*Does it encompass any specific age group? (young, middle-aged, elderly, all of them)*

Post secondary-school age: because otherwise you're just "boy" or "girl". :-)

By the way I did once (long ago) hear "old woman" (not "old girl") being used pejoratively: during a game of football at school, being told that you're "playing like an old woman".

I'd say that referring to a woman as "old girl" is affectionate.

---

Even if you could say it to someone, you might not want to: because it might sound "[Hooray Harry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hooray_Henry)" unless you're someone who's too kind to be criticised.

Did I mention it might seem slightly condescending? Because it *is* familiar, it would be slightly taking liberties with someone who's a social superior, or who's older and wiser than you are.

Maybe you could use it to someone to whom you're about to give some advice.

On the other hand you might, possibly, use it as a term of an endearment, to an old friend. Again, because it is familiar. But it could sound weird, if it's not the kind of person you are and the kind of person your friend is.

Another reason why you might not use it is that, for such a familiar mode of address, it may be overly formal. If you know someone that well, why not use their given name to address them? So maybe it is or was a term that you could use with semi-strangers, who you're thrown together with in a institutional setting: e.g. when you meet someone because you're both in the army, in a club, in government, perhaps in the judiciary, etc.
And I strongly suspect its use has declined at all institutions, for example because any reference to an "[old boy network](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_boy_network)" is now politically incorrect.

Comment: I have tried to touch on its being used, a) within family; b) to strangers; and c) to friends. But not its being used **about** strangers, e.g. as in the OP's, "*Who is that old girl you were talking to?*"

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is. And if you don't believe me, just try it with any woman on the street. Also, see if the slap you receive is mitigated by saying what you think it means and see if you get anything like an apology.